# how to import .xls file into SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I have an issue with importing .xls file into SQLite database. I am working on windows xp and using a SQLite manager for maintain the database. I can import the .csv file to the database by using availabel options in menu bar but I can't import the .xls file into this. I want to directly import the .xls file without converting into .csv file.

If I use the .csv file for import the data then it doesn't give the proper output due to comma separation.

Is there any way to import like this? Please give me the proper solution

I already googled but no solution I got.

Comment: You could save it as a csv (or use a tool to that) and [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-can-i-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite/1045961#1045961)

Comment: Rohan@: I already checked that link and I maintioned that I want to directly import from .xls file

Comment: you can first convert it to a csv (using a tool like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-command-line)) and then import the csv.. I don't think there is a direct way.

Comment: This online tool can convert from xls or xlsx to SQLite: http://converttosqlite.com/ Full Disclosure: I wrote it - hope it helps!

Comment: Try this python code [exceltosql](https://gist.github.com/shahzebiam/0c2694cc17d7e39e9d12)